# Problems with inserting DbGeography values on Oracle and dotConnect

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, dotconnect

we have a model class with a DbGeography property. Now we want to make our system work on an oracle database and evaluating dotConnect by devart for this purpose. Initial migration was good enough and created an appropriate table and mapped the DbGeography property as SDO_GEOMETRY typed column in oracle db.

Now we get "Value with type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography not supported." when calling SaveChanges after adding an object with the DbGeography-property to our context.

Is there a way to fix this or any workaround for this.

Regards,
Maxim

Answer (score 0):

We recommend setting SpartialServiceType and other EF options

EITHER in a static constructor of the context:

```
var config = Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.Configuration.OracleEntityProviderConfig.Instance;
config.SpatialOptions.SpatialServiceType = SpatialServiceType.NetTopologySuite;
```

OR in *.config:

```
 <Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity xmlns="http://devart.com/schemas/Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity/1.0">
  <SpatialOptions SpatialServiceType="NetTopologySuite" />
 </Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity>
```

For more information, refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Spatials.html.

We will investigate the possibility of supporting Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll (like it is implemented for NetTopologySuite), but there is no any timeframe at the moment.